# Hibernate CacheException

Tags: hibernate

i try to create and fill a database with the help of hibernate.

My Hibernate-Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
   "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url">
        jdbc:h2:C:\Users\data\datastore
    </property>
    <property name="connection.username">admin</property>
    <property name="connection.password">admin</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <mapping class="de.model.Player" />
    <mapping class="de.model.Team" />
    <mapping class="de.model.Goal" />
    <mapping class="de.model.Match" />
</session-factory>
```

My Data-Access-Object:

```
public class DAO {

/**
 * 
 */
public void clean() {
    Session session = DBSessionHandler.getSessionFactoryInstance().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    session.createQuery("Delete from Player").executeUpdate();
    session.createQuery("Delete from Team").executeUpdate();
    session.createQuery("Delete from Goal").executeUpdate();
    session.createQuery("Delete from Match").executeUpdate();
    session.flush();
    session.clear();
    transaction.commit();
}

/**
 * 
 * @param player
 */
public void insertPlayer(Player player) {
    Session session = DBSessionHandler.getSessionFactoryInstance().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    session.save(player);
    transaction.commit();
}

/**
 * 
 * @param team
 */
public void insertTeam(Team team) {
    Session session = DBSessionHandler.getSessionFactoryInstance().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    session.save(team);
    transaction.commit();
}

/**
 * 
 * @param goal
 */
public void insertGoal(Goal goal) {
    Session session = DBSessionHandler.getSessionFactoryInstance().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    session.save(goal);
    transaction.commit();
}

/**
 * 
 * @param match
 */
public void insertMatch(Match match) {
    Session session = DBSessionHandler.getSessionFactoryInstance().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    session.save(match);
    transaction.commit();
}

/**
 * 
 * @param player
 */
public void updatePlayer(Player player) {
    Session session = DBSessionHandler.getSessionFactoryInstance().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    session.update(player);
    transaction.commit();
}

/**
 * 
 * @param team
 */
public void updateTeam(Team team) {
    Session session = DBSessionHandler.getSessionFactoryInstance().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    session.update(team);
    transaction.commit();
}

/**
 * 
 * @param goal
 */
public void updateGoal(Goal goal) {
    Session session = DBSessionHandler.getSessionFactoryInstance().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    session.update(goal);
    transaction.commit();
}

/**
 * 
 * @param match
 */
public void updateMatch(Match match) {
    Session session = DBSessionHandler.getSessionFactoryInstance().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    session.update(match);
    transaction.commit();
}

/**
 * 
 * @param player
 */
public void deletePlayer(Player player) {
    Session session = DBSessionHandler.getSessionFactoryInstance().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    session.delete(player);
    transaction.commit();
}

/**
 * 
 * @param team
 */
public void deleteTeam(Team team) {
    Session session = DBSessionHandler.getSessionFactoryInstance().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    session.delete(team);
    transaction.commit();
}

/**
 * 
 * @param goal
 */
public void deleteGoal(Goal goal) {
    Session session = DBSessionHandler.getSessionFactoryInstance().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    session.delete(goal);
    transaction.commit();
}

/**
 * 
 * @param match
 */
public void deleteMatch(Match match) {
    Session session = DBSessionHandler.getSessionFactoryInstance().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    session.delete(match);
    transaction.commit();
}
}
```

My Main:

```
public class Main {
/**
 * 
 */
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);
/**
 * 
 */
private static DAO dao = new DAO();
/**
 * 
 */
private static XMLReader reader = new XMLReader();

/**
 * 
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Document allTeams = reader.parseFile("src/main/resources/teams.xml");
        Document allMatches = reader.parseFile("src/main/resources/matches.xml");

        List<Element> teams = allTeams.getRootElement().getChildren("Team");

        for(Element team: teams) {
            Team newTeam = new Team();
            newTeam.setId(Integer.parseInt(team.getChild("teamID").getValue()));
            newTeam.setName(team.getChild("teamName").getValue());
            newTeam.setIconUrl(team.getChild("teamIconURL").getValue());
            newTeam.setStadion(team.getChild("stadion").getValue());
            newTeam.setPlayer(new HashSet<Player>());

            List<Element> players = team.getChildren("player");

            for(Element player: players) {
                Player newPlayer = new Player();
                newPlayer.setName(player.getValue());
                newPlayer.setTeam(newTeam);

                newTeam.getPlayer().add(newPlayer);
            }

            dao.insertTeam(newTeam);

            for(Player player: newTeam.getPlayer()) {
                dao.insertPlayer(player);
            }
        }

        // dao.clean();
    } catch(RuntimeException e) {
        try {
            Session session = DBSessionHandler.getSessionFactoryInstance().getCurrentSession();

            if(session.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                session.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
        } catch(HibernateException e1) {
            log.error("Error rolling back transaction");
        }

        throw e;
    } catch (JDOMException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

When executing the Main i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.cache.CacheException:     net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another unnamed CacheManager already exists in the same VM.  Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name.
```

How do i have to solve this problem? I did this first hibernate-try with 
help of a tutorial. in that tutorial it worked ^^

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">
net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory
</property>
```

to

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">
net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
</property>
```